# I'm having trouble dynamically allocating my struct

Tags: c++

I created a simple program to help me understand how to Dynamically Allocate a structure. I want the program to  gets 5 names and 5 accounts from the user, and display the names and the accounts. I know a pointer is like a reference variable, the only differences instead of passing the value, it passes the address of the variable. I set a breaking point for line 23 ("getline(std::cin,clientPtr[count].name);"), line 25 ("std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits::max(),'\n');"),
line 27 ("std::cin >>clientPtr[count].accounts;"), line 40 ("std::cout <<"Name:" << clientPtr[count].name;"), line 41 ("std::cout <<"Name:" << clientPtr[count].name;"),line 31(    showInfo(&client);). When I debugged it shows that line 41 is not executing. It should display the names and the accounts of each client. In this case it's not. I'm not sure why, just a little background on me, I'm new to C++, as well with using the debugger. I'm using xcode 8.2 and the debugger I am using is lldb. I'm here to learn, so anything will help. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
struct BankInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string accounts;

};

void showInfo(BankInfo*);

int main()
{
    BankInfo client;

    BankInfo* clientPtr=nullptr;

    clientPtr = new BankInfo[5];

    for(int count =0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your name:";
        getline(std::cin,clientPtr[count].name);
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
        std::cout << "Enter you account number:";
        std::cin >>clientPtr[count].accounts;


    }
    showInfo(&client);


    return 0;
}
void showInfo(BankInfo* clientPtr)
{
    for(int count =5; count < 5; count++)
    {
        std::cout <<"Name:" << clientPtr[count].name;
        std::cout <<"Account:" << clientPtr[count].accounts;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(int count =5; count < 5; count++)` -- Do you see something wrong with this line?

Comment: `showInfo(&client);` see anything wrong there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are handing the wrong thing to `showInfo()`. You have two variables.. a single BankInfo variable and a dynamic allocated array with size 5.

You want to iterate over the latter and not the former.

Changing `showInfo(&client);`to `showInfo(clientPtr);` should do the trick perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed the solution I made several mistakes, but thank you for the suggestion. Here's what I did.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
struct BankInfo
{
    std::string name;
    std::string accounts;

};

void showInfo(BankInfo*);

int main()
{
    BankInfo client;

    BankInfo* clientPtr=nullptr;

    clientPtr = new BankInfo[5]; //Allocate an array of BankInfo struct on the heap

    for(int count =0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter your name:";
        getline(std::cin,clientPtr[count].name); // stores the value in the name member
        std::cout << "Enter you account number:";
        std::cin >>clientPtr[count].accounts; // stores the value in accounts member
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

    }
    showInfo(clientPtr);

    delete [] clientPtr;
    clientPtr = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
void showInfo(BankInfo* clientPtr)
{
    for(int count =0; count < 5; count++)
    {
           std::cout <<"\nName:" << clientPtr[count].name; // dereference the pointer to the structure 
           std::cout <<"\nAccount:" << clientPtr[count].accounts; // dereference the pointer to the structure

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int count=1 ; count<=5 ; count++)
{
//do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: I would think `for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++)` no?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Try This 

void showInfo(BankInfo* clientPtr)
{
    for(int count =0; count < 5; count++)
    {
        std::cout <<"Name:" << clientPtr[count].name;
        std::cout <<"Account:" << clientPtr[count].accounts;
    }
}